# Changing collection view data source on tap

Tags: swift, performance, uicollectionview, xcode-instruments

I have a collection view with a gradually increasing number of items. Initially there could be 100 items displayed. Then, based on selecting one, I want to insert items after the last currently visible item. I also want to refresh what had already been added but I've yet to see.

`performBatchUpdates` does what I need it to do, but if you select/unselect multiple items quickly, you get a gradual decrease in performance.

This is what I have so far on every cell tap:

```
performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
    collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(reloadIndexPaths)
    collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(insertIndexPaths)
}, completion: { (completed: Bool) -> Void in
```

Any thoughts on what I could do to smooth out performance? Instruments validates my assumption that this is the area of concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it `async` like this:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () in
         performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
           collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(reloadIndexPaths)
           collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(insertIndexPaths)
          }, completion: { (completed: Bool) -> Void in
          ...
      }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the whole thing is wrapped in dispatch_async already, which is why I'm a little unsure about what is best.